# Is it possible to disable orientation change for a Symbian Web App?

Tags: symbian, orientation, portrait

Just a simple little problem. My app only needs to work in portrait mode and landscape looks funky. Is there a way to disable landscape mode in the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

1) In your AppUI's ConstructL(), call:

BaseConstructL(CAknAppUi::EAppOrientationPortrait);

2) At any time, call:

AppUi()->SetOrientationL(CAknAppUi::EAppUiOrientationPortrait);

See also this [Forum Nokia article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Change_screen_orientation_of_UI_application).